# WCF service not show metadata on server (return 404), only locally it works

Tags: wcf, soap, metadata, basic-authentication

I have a problem with metadata (wsdl on service soap).

Locally everything works fine. and at the address https: // localhost / DataImportSoapService /? wsdl the wsdl is exposed.

Nothing is shown on the server. Return 404.
I state that I have other active services in WCF and that the other .svc are correctly exposed.
While this basicHttpBinding service with basic auth doesn't work.
So on the server I activated everything:

[image]

[image]

My web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DatineoUser" value="zzzzzz" />
    <add key="DatineoPass" value="xxxx" />
    <add key="UrlServiceNewEra" value="https://xxxxx/common/importDataCarrier?satcode=datineo" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior" name="TA_service_library_BA.DataImportSoapService">
        <endpoint address="datineoV1" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_LargeBinding" name="EndpointAVeryBigSum_BasicAuthentication"
          contract="TA_service_library_BA.IDataImportSoapService" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost/DataImportSoapService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="TA_service_library_BA.ServiceAuthenticator, TA_service_library_BA"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBinding_LargeBinding" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00" maxBufferSize="15728640" maxBufferPoolSize="15728640" maxReceivedMessageSize="15728640">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My classes:

```
namespace TA_service_library_BA
{
    public class ServiceAuthenticator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                throw new SecurityTokenException("Username and password required");
            if (!(userName == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatineoUser"] && password == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatineoPass"]))
                throw new FaultException(string.Format("Wrong username ({0}) or password ", userName));
        }
    }
}

namespace TA_service_library_BA
{
    // NOTA: è possibile utilizzare il comando "Rinomina" del menu "Refactoring" per modificare il nome di interfaccia "IDataImportService" nel codice e nel file di configurazione contemporaneamente.
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://sen.company.com")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    public interface IDataImportSoapService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        PushResponse PushDataArray(PushData pushDataArray);
        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    }
}

namespace TA_service_library_BA
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
    public class DataImportSoapService : IDataImportSoapService
    {
        public PushResponse PushDataArray(PushData pushDataArray)
        {
            PushResponse responsePush = new PushResponse();
            try
            {
                string authkey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatineoUser"] + ":" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatineoPass"];
                string encAuthkey = CommFun.Base64Encode(authkey);
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UrlServiceNewEra"]);
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encAuthkey);
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(pushDataArray);
                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                }
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

                if (response.StatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK) || response.StatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.NoContent))
                {
                    //istanzio la risposta contenitore
                    responsePush.success = true;
                    responsePush.message = responseString;
                }
                else
                {
                    //istanzio la risposta contenitore
                    responsePush.success = false;
                    responsePush.message = responseString;
                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //istanzio la risposta contenitore
                responsePush.success = false;
                responsePush.message = ex.Message;
            }
            return responsePush;
        }
    }
}
```

Why do some projects expose at least the .svc while this last service gives me 404 to the .svc file?

Beyond this then I don't understand what the hell is wrong with the configuration ... with IIS express everything goes .. on the server no.

Thanks for your help. I've been banging my head for a week and a half. I have tried the impossible. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following conditions:

1. Whether the permission of the managed directory is granted.
2. Whether the.NET version matches.
3. Is there a valid certificate on the site.
4. Try to put the image in the same path and find it.